# By what means would I unsync Outlook Address Book items synced from a specific source, particularly CRM?

Tags: vba, outlook, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

So I installed the Dynamics CRM Client for Outlook and wired up a client's CRM to do some work for them. Unbeknownst to me, Microsoft decided to auto-opt-in the Contact sync to the Outlook Address Book. IE: All the contacts from the CRM's Contact entity have now synced into my primary Outlook Address Book. I now have over 35k contacts that I do **NOT** want in there.

Is there a way to "unsync" specific items from the Outlook Address Book that were synced from a particular source? Obviously, I only want those CRM contacts removed. Is there an API or something I could use to traverse the Address Book that would allow me to:

a) Identify which contacts came from the CRM

b) Delete them

Or, if there is a non-programmatic method of doing so? That would be best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to sort the contacts by the creation date and delete the contacts that were added after you installed Dynamics CRM.

Comment: Sometimes the simplest of solutions just don't come to mind. You're a most excellent gentleman sir!